# Laravel functions arrays and datamodels

Tags: php, laravel

I have been working on some old code that was given to me to play with and edit to get familar with and i was wondering if you can see if what i am doing is syntactly sound as im confusing myself with the laravel framework. i basically want to know if im close to what my comments are wanting to do and whether my code and comments marry up or a i missing the point? As im getting the following error message

The error message im getting when running this command through my terminal is

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$email' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' in /Libraryenter code here/WebServer/Documents/healthandsafetymonitoringsystem.local/app/commands/IncompleteReportsCommand.php on line 157
```

my code is as follows

```
// This function uses the parameters $data that is passed to this function each time
// the fire() function loops through and assigns and determines that there is a duereport
private function sendGeneralManagerEmail($data)
{
    // create an array called 'Park' that is poulated via the $data parameters
    // in the function and is specificly looking for the ParkName entries 
    $data['Park'] = $Park->ParkName;
    //for each item in that array use $ParkName as a key and name each elements $name
    foreach($data['Park'] as $ParkName => $name)
    {
        // Every time i loop through this file get the element $name and 
        // attach this prefix to it
        $email = $name."generalmanager@parkholidays.com";
    }
        // Then send an email with new $email variable as a reciepient and sending the $data passed 
        // from the fire() function and used within this functions parameters
        Mail::send('emails.GeneralManager', $data, function($message) use $email
        {
            $message->to( $email, 'General Manager')->subject('[Urgent] Health & Safety Reports');
        });
}
```

Sorry for the dumb question if there are any articles regarding arrays/data models and php functions in laravel that you suggest reading thatll be great. This is a steep learnign curve as i have gone from plain php coding on notepad ++ to laravel 4 and i cant seem to find a nice tutorial that goes from the start to finish with a complete novice in mind.

Regards mike

Comment: After a bit of thinking lol, i have narrowed the scope of my question, Basically the $data that is being passed into the sendgeneralManager function($data) is being sent from my fire function and what i want is to be able to get a particular entry from $data that is the park name. i Hope this a better clarifictation of my original message

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding your error

You just have a PHP syntax error. Here's the code you want:

```
// This function uses the parameters $data that is passed to this function each time
// the fire() function loops through and assigns and determines that there is a duereport
private function sendGeneralManagerEmail($data)
{
    // create an array called 'Park' that is poulated via the $data parameters
    // in the function and is specificly looking for the ParkName entries 
    $data['Park'] = $Park->ParkName;
    //for each item in that array use $ParkName as a key and name each elements $name
    foreach($data['Park'] as $ParkName => $name)
    {
        // Every time i loop through this file get the element $name and 
        // attach this prefix to it
        $email = $name."generalmanager@parkholidays.com";
    }
        // Then send an email with new $email variable as a reciepient and sending the $data passed 
        // from the fire() function and used within this functions parameters
        Mail::send('emails.GeneralManager', $data, function($message) use ($email)
        {
            $message->to( $email, 'General Manager')->subject('[Urgent] Health & Safety Reports');
        });
}
```

See the `use $email` you had that I've changed to `use ($email)` in the closure at the end.

### Regarding your more general question about coding

I can see a few things that don't look right to me. Is this code an exact replica of the function or have you removed some code?

Comment: Hello thanks for quick reply this was given to me by a work collegue which only had the mail function and and a string to pass to the recipient eamil to.

Comment: In which case I have a couple of comments - first off the line that begins `$data['Park'] = ` seems out of context to me - it references a `$Park` variable that appears to be undefined. As such, that code is likely to error. Additionally to that, the `Mail::send` call you have here should be within the foreach loop, but is currently outside of it. Otherwise the code doesn't look too bad to me. But yeah, as carousel says, it's really hard to help you out as we don't know more context, and writing code for you won't necessarily help you out anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your response i understand that, and i would want my code written for me as its for me to find out and learn. 
 
After a bit of thinking lol, i have narrowed the scope of my question, Basically the $data that is being passed into the sendgeneralManager function($data) is being sent from my fire function and what i want is to be able to get a particular entry from $data that is the park name and then send it via the mail finction. i Hope this a better clarifictation of my original message

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say more about you code, since it is taken out of context.
Writing new code as answer, will confuse you more.

So it is better to:

Subscribe to [laracast](https://laracasts.com/) and you will learn everything you need to know about Laravel. Also there is new, updated Laravel 4.1 [documentation](https://leanpub.com/l4-offline-doc)

Comment: Thank you for your reply i will sign asap!